# Turn Autocomplete on

Tags: customization

I would like to set the autocompleete to on for the post title.

Please can somenone tell me how to do this.

Thanks

[image: Autocomplete]

**Update**

Note The autocomplete=*off* setting is removed when the plugin is activated it is not set to "on"

[image: Plugin Activated]

Comment: Wow that is fantastic, just what I need, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no hook available to change it.

You can see it in `wp-admin/edit-form-avanced.php`:

```
<label class="screen-reader-text" id="title-prompt-text" for="title"><?php echo $title_placeholder; ?></label>
<input type="text" name="post_title" size="30" value="<?php echo esc_attr( htmlspecialchars( $post->post_title ) ); ?>" id="title" spellcheck="true" autocomplete="off" />
```

You'll have to change it using JavaScript when the page has been loaded.

I made a [little plugin](https://gist.github.com/rrikesh/1c2311203b096fb65f29) that will fix your issue. Here's the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Autocomplete Title
 * Description: Sets the autocomplete attribute to true on WordPress post titles
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/175585/17305
 */

namespace WPSE\AutocompleteTitle;

/**
 * Sets autocomplete attribute to true on WordPress post titles
 */
function set_autocomplete_on_title() {
    echo '<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        if( $("#title").length ){
            $("#title").removeAttr("autocomplete");
        }
    });
    </script>';
}
\add_action( 'admin_footer', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\set_autocomplete_on_title' );
```

When you activate the plugin, it will remove the `autocomplete` attribute from the title's `<input>`.

Comment: HI RRikesh I saved the file as autocomplete.php , I then saved it as a zip file and uploaded it as a plugin. However it did not work. Have i done it correctly?

Comment: Did you activate the plugin? Is the JavaScript part being injected in your page?

Comment: Hi RRikesh, yes I activated the plugin. When the plugin is activated it is removing the "autocomplete="off", however it is not setting it to "autocomplete="on". I think this is why it is not working.

Comment: You can see this is the image I have attached in the main question

Comment: By default, all fields "have" `autocomplete="on"`. Removing `autocomplete="off"` is the same as having `autocomplete="on"`

Comment: thanks RRikesh, but the autocomplete does not work , when you type with the plugin activated. Do you know why?

Comment: I tried and it works. If you don't see the `autocomplete="off"`, it's working.

Comment: Thank RRikesh, But It still does not work for me. It is not bringing up previous titles I have written. I dont know what I could be doing wrong

Comment: That's exactly what the plugin is meant to do...